# Is there a way to implement concurrent queue using memcached?

Tags: concurrency, queue, memcached

I am working on key-value database similar to `memcached`.

From some time I am thinking how one might implement concurrent message queue using `memcache` without using locks and without using "help from the server" - this is how `Redis` manage do it.

In most implementations there are key_to_head and key_to_tail.

For example PUSH data seems to be easy:

1. increment head
2. set data

However whats happen, if between the two operations, a reader decide to POP?

I checked some implementations, but all of them not really work or I am not "clever enough" to see the trick they using...

Comment: It takes “server support” of _some_ kind - a CAS or primitives that can emulate such or a larger transaction / exclusive region with visibility guarantees. Consider that Redis has operations like SETNX (“set if not set”) which are singular atomic _on a single instance_. However, even this fails with replication — See https://redis.io/topics/distlock which is a good read and discusses various concerns.

Comment: And, I’m not surprised if there are implementations that are not correctly concurrency safe.. providing information on what this “similar” database is might reveal some features/approaches suitable for this task.

Comment: @user2864740 - https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4 , no it has not. I am researching what I need to add, without bloating it.

Comment: SETNX can do a lock. but then the client can crash, so you need to set expiration. But then when you remove the "lock" key you need to check if it is the same you did set. For server help I meant LPOP, SPOP (I agree is not exactly queue) and similar, that do all job on the server.

Comment: Minimally, I’m relatively certain an atomic CAS operation is required if not using locking (this can be done with the memcached model, at least insofar as a single instance). Without the required primitives..